# Tensorflow: extracting predictions from "Layer Module"

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I am following the Tensorflow's "Layer Module" from this tutorial link https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers. You might be able to help me how can I get the results of the predictions and its respective probabilities.
I need to see it for further understanding the model. And if there is a way I can save the results - predictions and probabilities to csv.

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually found a way on this and it is very simple as I thought. I was thinking some might have similar question so here it is. Tensorflow is kind a new framework to work on machine learning models but I eventually realize that this is quite easy.

Tensorflow has this *.predict(...) function on the model you created with tf and it returns the predictions variable you define on your model which contains "classes" and "probabilities"

On your model for an example:

```
some_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn,
    model_dir=...)
```

you can do this for prediction (as we know it)

```
prediction_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x": test_feats}, #given you have this variable containing the test data
    y=test_labels, #and the equivalent label for the test data
    num_epochs=1,
    shuffle=False)
prediction_results = some_classifier.predict(input_fn=prediction_input_fn)
```

and then the variable *prediction_results* contains the values for predicted class and its probabilities which you can then save (e.g using Panda)

```
save = panda.DataFrame(list(prediction_results))  
save.to_csv("file.csv")
```

The above code snip works well given you already written a code within your model a container for predictions such as below:

```
predictions = {
  "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1), 
  "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
```

}